# Page load scrolling fails on refresh on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Upon loading, my React app is designed to scroll to a certain spot specified in the hash fragment of the url. The page is not actually scrolling, but rather a div on the page.

This happens correctly on the first visit to the page, e.g. when you paste the url into the address bar and press enter. But on Chrome and Opera, if you subsequently refresh the page, it does not scroll and you are left at the top of the page. On Firefox and Safari, it does scroll when the page is refreshed.

There's a codesandbox of it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-indoctrination-k4pk0)

EDIT: **Instructions for reproducing**

After opening the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-indoctrination-k4pk0), wait for it to build and then visit this url in Chrome.

https://k4pk0.sse.codesandbox.io/#omniscience

Choose "catholic" from the modal dialog. The page will scroll to the specified anchor. Refresh the page. The page will not scroll.

Repeat this using Firefox. The page will scroll after a refresh.

Comment: You are being way too vague with your problem, you can't just expect people to sift through the whole project and find the issue. Either get a minimal example that has the same behaviour, or at least show us how you're trying to accomplish the scrolling in the first place. What did you do to make it scroll? What hashes can we test to see it in action?

Comment: Please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: .questions-list check and below CSS selector in your app, the mentioned CSS selector has postion:fixed and height sets just 115px, so you can scroll on this page....

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=932551  "Reloading the page does not cause us to scroll to the fragment."  "We currently don't process the fragment on reload (same for element fragment anchors)"

Answer (score 0):

you can try to scroll after the document is ready:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let tag = this.props.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (tag ) {
        let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[tag ]);
        if (node) {
            node.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
}
```

With the refs in the page

```
<h4 ref='catholic'>Catholic</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it for me. Did it fix it for you? Also, I noticed another oddity. When I clicked the link above to the codesandbox site preview without first clicking the one to the codesandbox source code, it actually worked properly in Chrome. Then I opened the source code before opening the preview and it didn't work. Also, also, I vaguely remember trying "scrollIntoView" early in the project and it gave me problems on my iPhone. Also, also, also findDOMNode is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your componentDidUpdate runs before componentDidMount on your QuestionReader component, if your view isn't rendered you can't scroll into that, you need to call `this.scrollToElement()` on componentDidMount.

You can also get the current hash using `window.location.hash` and save some `props.history.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, "").replace(/\./g, " ");`

Hope it helps.